# how to dplyr filter match?

Tags: r, dplyr

I guess this might be a rather simple question, but how to do this (base R):

```
df <- data.frame(x=10:1,y=(1:10)^2)
df[match(c(3,5,7), df$x),]
```

in idiomatic dplyr parlance:

```
tb <- dplyr::as.tbl(df)
dplyr::filter(tb, ??? )
```

or, in other words, what should go into `???` to make it functionally equivalent to the first snippet? Please note that the order of rows in resulting dataframe/tibble is relevant.

Comment: @RichScriven: nope, order of `c(3,5,7)` is not preserved in resulting tibble.

Comment: K then use `slice` instead.  `dplyr::slice(df, match(c(3, 5, 7), x))`

Comment: @RichScriven: Thanks!

Comment: @RichScriven: please post an answer, and I am glad to flag it as the right one.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer.  I don't mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @RichScriven: use `dplyr::slice(df, match(c(3, 5, 7), x))` instead of `dplyr::filter`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `filter` as well:

```
df %>% 
  filter( x %in% c(3, 5, 7)) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

Output:

```
  x  y
1 7 16
2 5 36
3 3 64
```

`sqldf`package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf('SELECT *
      FROM df 
      WHERE x IN (3, 5, 7)
      GROUP BY x
      LIMIT 3')
```